# Find date ranges that include the weekend using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, intervals

I have a pandas DataFrame in Python with two columns denoting start and end date.
I want to:

- Given two pandas Series as start as end dates as input...
- Determine, for each pair of start-end dates, if any date between the interval [start, end) (i.e. including start but excluding end) is either a Friday or a Saturday...
- Output a pandas Series as a boolean.
- The solution should be relatively fast as I am working with over 2M rows.

The dataset looks like:

```
start       end
2013-08-02  2013-08-04
2014-11-24  2014-11-28
2013-10-29  2013-10-31
2013-12-06  2013-12-10
2014-08-15  2014-08-17
```

I would be expecting something like:

```
has_weekend
TRUE
FALSE
FALSE
TRUE
TRUE
```

My current approach is quite slow for a DataFrame that has close to 2M rows.
Here's the code:

```
df.apply(lambda x: np.any(np.in1d([d.weekday() for d in pd.date_range(x.start, x.end)],[4,5])), axis=1)
```

Any ideas?

**SOLUTION**
The fastest solution was a modified answer from @Anton VBr 's

```
s = df.start.dt.dayofweek
e = df.end.dt.dayofweek
dt = (df.end- df.start).dt.days
has_weekend = ( ((s >= 4) & (s != 6)) | ( e>=5) | ((e < s) & (s != 6)) | (dt >= 6) )
```

Comment: The lack of data in your question isn't helping.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I have added a snippet of the data for more clarity.

Comment: For this input, what is the expected? `0, 1, 3, 4`?

Comment: Check again, it should be T T F T T, your current solution gives the same.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ you are right, it should give T T F T T. I forgot to exclude the end date. Nevertheless, my actual solution is way to slow. I will try with yours asap.

Comment: Fair enough. I have edited my answer, it works for your use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought about some logical operators and these should do, however they aren't any time improvement on the small set I tested.

```
s = df.start.dt.dayofweek
e = df.end.dt.dayofweek
(((s >= 4) & (s != 6)) | (( e>=4) & (s != 6)) | (e < s))
```

Comment: This is almost the answer I was looking for but it definitely sped things up...
while my initial solution took 15 minutes to run, your solution with the modifications took 15 seconds. (Without the mods it took 450ms but was not accounting for long periods of time between dates). I have posted the answer in the edits just in case.